# Unir 2 consultas y crear nueva columna SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un desarrollo de un proyecto personal en el cual estoy necesitando unir varias consultas de sql, pero cuando se unan se deberia de crear una nueva columna en dicha union, e tratado de buscar en internet pero no encuentro algo similar, solo me encontre el join pero no supe como implementarlo, estas serian las consultas que necesito unir:

```
set language spanish   
Select datename(month,([Fecha Inicial])) as Meses,count(*) as '0-2' from indicadores1 
where
year([Fecha Inicial])=2021 
and
(DATEDIFF(day,[Fecha Inicial],[Fecha Final])=1)
or
(DATEDIFF(day,[Fecha Inicial],[Fecha Final])=0)
and 
year([Fecha Inicial])=2021 
or
(DATEDIFF(day,[Fecha Inicial],[Fecha Final])=2)
and 
year([Fecha Inicial])=2021 
group by datename(month,([Fecha Inicial]))
order by 
case datename(month,([Fecha Inicial]))
when 'Enero' then 1
when 'Febrero' then 2
when 'Marzo' then 3
when 'Abril' then 4
when 'Mayo' then 5
when 'Junio' then 6
when 'Julio' then 7
when 'Agosto' then 8
when 'Septiembre' then 9 
when 'Octubre' then 10
when 'Noviembre' then 11
when 'Diciembre' then 12
end

Select datename(month,([Fecha Inicial])) as Meses ,count(*) as '3-5' from indicadores1 
where
year([Fecha Inicial])=2021 
and
(DATEDIFF(day,[Fecha Inicial],[Fecha Final])=3)
or
(DATEDIFF(day,[Fecha Inicial],[Fecha Final])=4)
and 
year([Fecha Inicial])=2021 
or
(DATEDIFF(day,[Fecha Inicial],[Fecha Final])=5)
and 
year([Fecha Inicial])=2021 
group by datename(month,([Fecha Inicial]))
order by 
case datename(month,([Fecha Inicial]))
when 'Enero' then 1
when 'Febrero' then 2
when 'Marzo' then 3
when 'Abril' then 4
when 'Mayo' then 5
when 'Junio' then 6
when 'Julio' then 7
when 'Agosto' then 8
when 'Septiembre' then 9 
when 'Octubre' then 10
when 'Noviembre' then 11
when 'Diciembre' then 12  
end
```

Trate de utilizar union pero lo que me da es una tabla donde me une las tablas pero duplica resultados de los meses:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo lo que necesito es que se cree una nueva columna seria algo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podría hacer el favor de ayudarme guiándome que debería hacer para obtener ese resultado?

Tambien les comento que la idea original consiste en replicar algunas formulas creadas en excel y hacerla en vb.net utilizando el entorno Visual Studio y como gestor de base de datos SQL-Server. Lo que necesito replicar es lo siguiente:

[image]

Esto toma los datos de la siguiente tabla de sql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En excel lo que hice fue hacer una pivot donde me agrupa los casos dependiendo de la cantidad de días que duro abierto y se calcula restando el tiempo inicial menos el tiempo final, luego se agrupa de 0-2 días 2-4 y así sucesivamente hasta llegar a 38-40 y de ahi realice una graficación de dichos datos. Hablando de la parte de graficación en vb.net se como realizarlo pero lo que actualmente necesito es cargas dichos datos a un datagriview para luego pasarlo a un grafico.

Entonces trate de realizar una sola consulta y traer todos esos datos pero no me sirvió, porque necesito varios condicionales para indicarle que si es 0 días o 1 día o x días se tiene que colocar en la columna correspondiente, por eso decidí crear varias consultas y unirlas en donde todas ellas compartirán la columna Meses pero por cada consulta se creara una nueva columna y se utilizara como referencia la primera columna de los meses.

Comment: Empieza desde el principio, olvidando el camino que has tomado (quizá equivocado) para lograr lo que quieres. Partimos de que tienes una tabla llamada `indicadores1` y quieres un resultado, ¿cierto? ¿Qué resultado es el que quieres exactamente (explícalo verbalmente, no desde el código que estás intentando ahora mismo), quizá haya una forma más simple de hacerlo, pero debes explicar con claridad el contexto y lo que esperas obtener. Muchas veces uno olvida el problema inicial, centrándose en querer hacer funcionar un código problemático. Plantea por tanto el **problema original**.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y usar pivot no funciono?

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, ya entendi mejor como usar el sitio, con respecto al pivot si funciona pero solo en excel, y lo que trato de hacer es replicarlo utilizando codigo para poder implementarlo en mi proyecto de visual studio.

Comment: Muy buenas noches @jachguate, le comento que ya había solucionado el problema, lo que hice fue utilizar Insert to , luego usaba Update y manualmente creaba las columnas, esto ocasiono que tuviera un código demasiado extenso y complejo, justo en el momento que logre hacer el código pensé que ya podía comenzar a llamarme desarrollador junior en SQL, pero con la solución que usted plantea me dio a entender que me falta muchísimo para poder siquiera considerarme un desarrollador de SQL, de verdad le agradezco por ilustrarme con ese código tan claro y dinámico, ya implemente el código en mi proyect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teniendo definidos los intervalos que quieres incluir, puedes valerte de una consulta en dos pasos para obtener el resultado que buscas.

A continuación incluyo un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que realiza los siguientes pasos:

1. Un CTE `indicadores1` simula tus datos de entrada. Contiene solo los campos de ID y dos campos de fecha que representan la fecha inicio y fin de cada *incidente* o *servicio*.
2. El CTE `IntervaloIndicador` se encarga de:

   - Filtrar los datos de entrada para quedarse con un solo año de operaciones
   - Incluir el mes al que pertenece cada registro (no el nombre del mes, sino su número. Ya al final, puedes convertir este dato en el nombre fácilmente).
   - En base a la diferencia de días entre las fechas, indica el intervalo al que pertenece. Dado que tus *intervalos* tienen traslapes, no he generado los mismos de tu ejemplo, pues no sabría dónde incluir un registro que da como resultado 2 días, si en `0-2` on en `2-4`. Si la forma de hacerlo es diferente en tu caso, considero esto un ajuste menor, que debes realizar en este punto. Lo importante aquí es que, al final, tengamos una lista definida de valores que puede tomar este campo.
3. Finalmente, ensamblo el resultado con una consulta que tiene la [cláusula *pivot*](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) y en la que, para cada columna, devuelvo la *cuenta* de las coincidencias.

Un trozo de código dice más que mil palabras:

```
with
indicadores1 as (
select *
  from (values (1, cast('20200907 06:56:00' as datetime), cast('20200907 07:34:00' as datetime))
             , (2, '20200907 06:57:00', '20200907 07:36:00')
             , (3, '20200908 14:11:00', '20200908 14:40:00')
             , (4, '20200909 06:27:00', '20200909 07:00:00')
             , (5, '20200909 08:54:00', '20200917 14:00:00')
             , (6, '20200909 08:56:00', '20200914 15:17:00')
             , (7, '20201021 08:58:00', '20201021 10:00:00')
             , (8, '20200909 07:26:00', '20200916 15:27:00')
       ) q1 (Id, FechaIni, FechaFin)
)
,
IntervaloIndicador as (
select   month(FechaIni) Mes
       , case 
           when datediff(day, FechaIni, FechaFin) <= 2 then '0-2'
           when datediff(day, FechaIni, FechaFin) <= 4 then '3-4'
           when datediff(day, FechaIni, FechaFin) <= 6 then '5-6'
           when datediff(day, FechaIni, FechaFin) <= 10 then '7-10'
           else '10+'
         end Intervalo
  from Indicadores1
 where year(FechaIni) = 2020
)
select Mes, [0-2], [3-4], [5-6], [7-10], [10+]
  from IntervaloIndicador as src
 pivot (count(Intervalo)
        for Intervalo in ([0-2], [3-4], [5-6], [7-10], [10+])
       ) as pvt
```

La salida producida por el ejemplo es:

```
Mes         0-2         3-4         5-6         7-10        10+
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
9           4           0           1           2           0
10          1           0           0           0           0

(2 rows affected)
```

Si comprendes el funcionamiento de la consulta, creo que no tendrás problemas para adaptarla a tu necesidad real. Luego de probarla, comienza por quitar el primer CTE para usar los datos reales de tu tabla, solo que debes ajustar los nombres de los campos.